# Writes and 'data' events in node.js sockets

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sockets, serialization

When passing data over a node.js socket, who ensures that the data is received/read in its entirety? The caller or node.js?

Does each write correspond to a single 'data' event? Do I need to explicitly check to ensure the length of the data received corresponds to what was written? In other words, do I have to maintain a length header?

Comment: websockets manage that themselves, if that's what you're asking about.

Comment: Are all node.js sockets websockets?

Comment: There's no guaranteed delivery if that's what you're asking.  Do you have a more specific question that can be illustrated with code?

Comment: @AgnelKurian: no, not at all. _sockets_ are a generic low-level thing, usually tcp. _WebSockets_ are a (slightly) higher level protocol with delivery guarantee, error handling, specified compression, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a write command:
`socket.write(data[, encoding][, callback])`, 
the `callback` parameter will be executed when the data is finally written out - this may not be immediately.

A single write command might cause a sequence of `data` events:

```
const readable = getReadableStreamSomehow();
readable.on('data', (chunk) => {
// chunk.length bytes of data received
});
```

The receiver needs to ensure that it receives the whole Buffer/String by checking the length of all received chunks. This will require having a length header or a similar marker.

P.S. The above answer holds for TCP like sockets.